# workflow 2013 not working after workflow created column is deleted from list

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a workflow 'xyz' on a list 'A'. The workflow was working fine, But when the column 'xyz' on list 'A' created by the workflow got deleted the workflow isn't working.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried republishing that workflow?

Comment: Yes, I have, but still, don't have the column and the workflow isn't working.

Comment: Do you have any running instances of that workflow? If not then you can try removing that workflow from list settings and again attaching the same workflow to list.

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap Thank you for your comment. Your approach is the correct one. I removed the workflow from the list settings and then published the workflow again. I got the related column and the workflow is also working fine.

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you to get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below approaches:

1. Try republishing the workflow.
2. Try removing the workflow from list settings and republish again by attaching the same workflow to list.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work. I created a column with the same name as the workflow and as a Hyperlink or Picture Type. I then published the workflow and then everything worked fine.

Comment: As per Ganesh Sanap at the above comment; removing the workflow from the workflow settings from list settings and then republishing it again resolved the issue.

Comment: Perhaps you could upvote his answer since it helped you?